# While accessing Fuse mounted Storage bucket, its showing 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: mount, fuse, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I have a google cloud project.
In that project. I have a VM instance.
I mounted uploads folder with Google Cloud Storage bucket using fuse.

While mounting I get an error like this,

```
Using mount point: /var/www/html/porject/app/webroot/uploads
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted
```

so i use sudo command
now i get reponse like this

```
Using mount point: /var/www/html/4thambit_v7/app/webroot/uploads
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
```

But i can't access the uploads folder, its showing 403 error (see image.)

ls -l command response like this

```
drwxrwxrwx.  1 root             root                     0 May  8 13:26 uploads
```

Anyone knows the correct steps to mount a folder in centos machine with Cloud Storage bucket.? if the gcs mount is successful. it will works similar to the local directory.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a permission error. I would suggest running gcsfuse including the `--foreground` and `--debug_fuse` options to see the full error.

Since you seems to have mounted the file system as root, the user accessing the file/folder doesn't have the permission to do so, as explained in this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions).

You can use `gcloud auth login`[(link)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) to login with your Google account and mount the file system after this command.

Answer (score 0):

Default GCSFUSE is READONLY, for Read/write should key json file:

1. Create json key for service account:
   https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/details/
2. Upload your json file to server
3. Run gcsfuse like:

   ```
   gcsfuse --key-file="/path/to/key-4c8e254b9365.json" bucket_name_path /path/to/mount/bucket
   ```